# Hide console window in remote process

Tags: c++, winapi

I have a windows application which invokes `CreateProcess` and then it exits. The process being invoked displays console and GUI windows at startup. I would like to hide the console window of the child process right when it starts.

More info:

- Process is NOT started with DETACHED_PROCESS flag.
- If injecting code with `FreeConsole()` to the remote process is the only way (I'm looking for a better one), is it not going to cause trouble with over-sensitive anti-viruses?

Comment: I assume that you cannot modify the process that is being launched? Why is it displaying a console window? Why do you not want that console window?

Comment: What about `CREATE_NO_WINDOW`?

Comment: @chris Thanks! Adding this flag worked, you can post it as an answer if you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `CREATE_NO_WINDOW` flag to start a console application without a console window. It's not the same as it being hidden, but it sounds like it's what you want.